# Where can I find the source code for the Android Development Tools (ADT) plugin for the Eclipse IDE?

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, adt

I can't find the source code for the Android Development Tools Plugin for Eclipse.  It seems to have been moved a few times, and when I google the question, the answers point to the wrong places.  Also http://source.android.com/discuss seems to be down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Android open source project downloaded in May 2011, the source for the eclipse plugins was in <aosp_root>/sdk/eclipse/plugins

```
$ cd sdk/eclipse/plugins; ls 
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt
com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer
com.android.ide.eclipse.tests
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms
com.android.ide.eclipse.pdt
com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview
```

Comment: If needed latest working plugin to eclipse: https://github.com/khaledev/ADT/releases

Answer (score 18):

For me

```
git clone "https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk"
```

worked

Answer (score 3):

Source code for ADT 22.6 is here

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/tools_r22.6/eclipse/plugins/

For older versions, Check following link and search for respective branch name as "tools_{version}"

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+refs

Answer (score 2):

You can find it here, try it:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/tools_r22.6/eclipse/plugins/